# return regex result from cmd output to variable

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm looking forward to get a string from an cmd output (ID of `tmutil destinationinfo`).

I have tested this regex with https://regex101.com/r/aI3yH2/1:

`/^.*?Name.+?backup02\nKind.+?\nID?\s+:\s([A-Z0-9\-]+)/s`

Looks like it's working, I'm searching for `backup01`, `backup02`, ...

But how can I grab the ID to a variable within a shell script?

Output is like this:

```
====================================================
Name          : backup02
Kind          : Local
Mount Point   : /Volumes/ext_backup01_02
ID            : BC51C9FA-DE8A-4BA3-B23E-AEC10E9E9F69
> ==================================================
Name          : backup01
Kind          : Network
URL           : afp://username@server02.local/backup01
Mount Point   : /Volumes/backup01
ID            : 009B3736-61C5-4996-B9BC-A5230BED7961
====================================================
Name          : backup03
Kind          : Network
URL           : afp://username@server67.local/backup03
Mount Point   : /Volumes/backup01
ID            : 1E9A3734-33D6-1316-C9B4-B143DA35D9F2
```

I really don't know how to handle this. Sample code 100% not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
ID=$(tmutil destinationinfo | sed -E '/^.*?Name.+?backup02\nKind.+?\nID?\s+:\s([A-Z0-9\-]+)/s')
echo $ID
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` (and `grep`, which would be the other popular regex matcher) are *line-oriented*; they process one line at a time. So multiline patterns won't work.

You can get `sed` to accumulate lines, but it's not very pretty. If you did that, you would find that the regex dialect recognized by `sed` is quite different from the one you are using in the online tool. In particular, `sed` doesn't implement non-greedy match.

You can probably do better with `awk`:

```
awk -F '[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*' \
    '$1 == "Name" && $2 == "backup02" { this_one = 1 }
     this_one && $1 == "ID" { print $2; exit }'
```